# Can't convert a Git repository to Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, github, github-for-windows, mercurial-convert

I have Git repository that I'm trying to convert to Mercurial. Running

> hg convert c:\code\git-repo

results in the following error:

> assuming destination git-repo-hg
>   initializing destination git-repo-hg repository
>   abort: cannot find required "git" tool

I have the [Git Hub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) application installed. Am I missing something else?

Comment: add git's path to path. Mercurial is a nightmare.

Comment: That was it. I modified the path and it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the help of dimo414 and J-16 SDiZ I was able to fix it. The problem was that GitHub for Windows didn't setup the location of Git into the Windows Path. Adding it to the path or simply running the hg convert from within the Git folder should work.

Answer (score 3):

From the error, it sounds like `hg convert` expects to be able to use the `git` command line tool.  What happens if you run `git --version` from the command prompt?  If not, you should be able to install it from the [Git downloads page](http://git-scm.com/downloads).  If it's already installed, you probably haven't added `git` to your [Windows `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

An alternative is to use [`hg-git`](http://hg-git.github.com/) which allows you to clone and push to a remote Git repository *as* a Mercurial repository.

Comment: I get 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add environment variable with 'git' name and path to git.exe value.